# The largest gap of elements in a list,Prolog

Tags: prolog

How to determine a predicate, like gap(+List,+A,-Output).
A is an element in List and we need to find another element B in List and abs(B-A) is larger than any other elements (named C) does abs(C-A), and the output is abs(B-A). I  have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Is this about a list of integers/numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Some predicates worth learning: [`maplist/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=maplist/3), [`select/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=select/3), [`forall/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=forall/2):

```
gap(List, A, Output) :-
    maplist([X,Y] >> (Y is abs(X-A)), List, Diffs),  % make a list of abs diffs
    select(Output, Diffs, Others),                   % select a diff
    forall(member(Other, Others), Output >= Other).  % check that is maximum
```

```
?- gap([1,10,50,100,120], 50, X).
X = 70
```